# Can the Hall effect drive a current?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

In the [Hall Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect) current is passed through a wide strip of metal in a perpendicular magnetic field. Since (some of) the negative charges in the metal move but the positive ones stay put, the magnetic field will cause a potential difference between the two sides of the strip:

[image: Source www.nde-ed.org/EducationResources/CommunityCollege/MagParticle/Physics/Measuring.htm]

How can this potential difference be measured? Can we simply connect a thin wire transversally between the two sides of the strip and see a current flow through it?

If no, then what prevents the current from flowing?

If yes, then aren't we getting something for nothing here? Our thin wire has some resistance -- where does the energy lost as heat in the wire come from? Does the total resistance of the primary circuit increase because we connect a wire between the two sides? *Increased* DC resistance because we add *more conducting material* to the system seems to be counterintuitive.

---

Image Source: https://www.nde-ed.org/EducationResources/CommunityCollege/MagParticle/Physics/Measuring.htm, via [Jahan Claes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/267042/10027).

Comment: I'm not sure the current title capture the subtlety of what is being asked here, but I haven't a better suggestion just now.

Comment: @dmckee: Hmm, I've attempted to improve it.

Comment: I think that's better. And in that form it seems like the answer should be trivially "yes", which leads us right to your questions of energy and resistance.

Comment: *"Does the total resistance of the primary circuit increase because we connect a wire between the two sides?"*  I don't follow.  Assuming an ideal voltage source, an *increase* in the primary circuit resistance would *reduce* the power delivered by the voltage source, not increase it.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri: Consider an ideal current source instead, then. (The Hall effect is current-dependent, after all, so it makes sense to keep that constant). In order to deliver the additional energy to heat up the transverse wire, the voltage would need to increase for the same current; thus increased resistance.

Comment: I think it's slightly backwards.  The Hall effect does not _drive_ the current, rather the magnetic field across the electric field from the potential in a conductor drives the current.  That is, the conductor has some particles which can move, others which cannot.  If both ions and electrons were allowed to move, like they can in a plasma, there would be no net current (e.g., look up ExB drifts).  That only electrons move under the influence of these fields is what results in a net current.